# Visual Basic 6 export special Polish characters to Excel

Tags: excel, unicode, vb6, character, polish

I have troubles with exporting data from VB6 program to Excel. I can't get Polish special letters `ś ń ć ź ż ą ę`. I get strange symbols instead. I tried to use chr() function but none of 0-255 possibilities give me what I need. 
How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Range("A1") = ChrW(378)
```

Here are the Unicode numbers for other Polish characters: http://character-code.com/polish-html-codes.php